# Multi-column format to 2 column format

Tags: text-processing

I have file like this:

```
1 a,b,c
2 z
3 d,f
```

and would like to have this format:

```
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 z
3 d
3 f
```

Comment: what did you do so far ? did you get any errors ? If so, please provide your commands and the output you received.

Comment: Are the values in the second column ever quoted (in order to contain a comma)?

Comment: If any of the existing answers solves your problem, please consider accepting it via the checkmark. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Awk solution:

```
$ cat file
1 a,b,c
2 z
3 d,f

$ awk '{ gsub(",", "\n"$1" "); print; }' file
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 z
3 d
3 f
```

Answer (score 0):

If your input is as simple as it looks, then here's a `bash` shell script doing the things that shell scripts are no good at:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
declare -a col2
while read col1 rest
do
  IFS=, read -a col2 <<< "$rest"
  for value in ${col2[*]}
  do
    printf "%s %s\n" "$col1" "$value"
  done
done < input
```

There are better ways to do it (`read -a` is bash-specific and not POSIX); there are other ways to do it (awk, perl). If your data is any more complicated `(1 a,"b,c",d)` or `(1 a,b\,c,d)` then this script will probably not do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it:

```
sild@:/tmp $ cat test
1 a,b,c
2 z
3 d,f
sild@:/tmp $ cat test.sh 
#!/bin/bash
separator=","
cat test | while read line; do
 head="`echo $line | cut -d" " -f1`"
 IFS="$separator" read -ra nodes <<< "`echo $line | cut -d" " -f2-`"
 for i in "${nodes[@]}"; do
         echo $head $i
     done
 done
sild@:/tmp $ ./test.sh 
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 z
3 d
3 f
sild@:/tmp $
```

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution :

```
perl -ane 'print map "$F[0] $_\n" ,split(",",$F[1])' file
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 z
3 d
3 f
```